# Magento hide attribute group if included attribute got no data

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set, category-attribute

We use this way to display attribute group names on the additional information tab on product page.
Currently when a attribute got no data, the entire attribute will be hidden.
I want to do the same for the attribute group name. So that if the attribute group got no attributes with data, it needs to be hidden.

This is our code:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additionalgroup = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="box-collateral box-additional">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional): $i++; ?>
        <h3><?php echo $this->__( $_additional['title'] )?></h3>
        <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
             <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Create if() statement before <h3> tag and check if your requirements are satisfied. That's not Magento issue.

Comment: I know, but I can't get it done. Do you know what if() statement I need for this?

Answer (score 0):

How out looping through the additional data once, collecting all the valid attributes in an array and then looping through that array again and skip over the empty groups.
Something like this (untested code):

```
$values = array();
foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional) {
    if (!isset($values[$_additional['title']])) {
        //maybe $_additional['title'] is not the best key here. See if you have an id or something unique available.
         $key = $_additional['title'];
         $values[$key] = array(); 
         $values[$key]['title'] = $_additional['title']; 
         $values[$key]['attributes'] = array();
         foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data) {
             $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
             if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) {
                  $values[$key]['attributes'][] = array(
                      'label' => $_data['label'],
                      'value' => $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])
                  );
             }
         }
    }
}
```

now loop through `$values` and print only sections where `count($values[$key]['attributes'])` is not zero.

```
<?php $i=0;foreach ($values as $key => $data) : ?>
     <?php if (count($data['attributes']) > 0) : ?>
          <h3><?php echo $this->__( $data['title'] )?></h3>
          <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
              <col width="25%" />
              <col />
              <tbody>
              <?php foreach ($data['attributes'] as $attribute) : ?>
                   <tr>
                       <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($attribute['label'])) ?></th>
                       <td class="data"><?php echo $attribute['value'] ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php endforeach;?>
              </tbody>
          </table>
          <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
     <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I tried the code, but it does not work. The entire additional information tab is empty.

Comment: It reads "(untested code)". It's just a suggestion for you to look into it and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a small piece of code. Find and open the attributes.phtml file. This file can be found here:`/app/design/frontend/[theme name]/[package name]/template/catalog/product/view/attribute.phtml`
Open the file and search for the following lines:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Replace the entire foreach loop with the following lines of code:

<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```